# On a special kind of Discrete Valuation Ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, extension-field, valuation-theory, transcendence-degree

Let $(R,\mathfrak m, \kappa) $ be a [Discrete Valuation Ring](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring) (i.e., a local PID) containing a field $k\hookrightarrow \kappa$ such that $\kappa$ has transcendence degree $1$ over $k$.  Let $K$ be the fraction field of $R$ and assume $K=k(a_1,...,a_n)$ for some $a_1,...,a_n\in K$. Also assume $\operatorname{tr.deg} K/k=1+\operatorname{tr.deg}\kappa/k$.

Then, how to show that $R$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra ?

Answer (score 2):

$R$ cannot be a finitely generated $k$-algebra because such an algebra posesses infinitely many prime ideals while $R$ has just two. However $R$ is a localization of a finitely generated $k$-algebra: let $\overline{x}$ be a transcendence basis of $\kappa/k$ and let $x\in R$ be a preimage of $\overline{x}$ under the residue map $R\rightarrow\kappa$. Then $k(x)\subset R$ and $K/k(x)$ is of transcendence degree equal to $1$.
The elements $a_k$ can be chosen in $R$ - replace $a_k$ by $a_k^{-1}$ if necessary. Then $A:=k(x)[a_1,\ldots ,a_n]\subseteq R$ is a $1$-dimensional noetherian domain. Hence its integral closure $B$ in $K$ is a Dedekind domain contained in $R$ by the theorem of Krull-Akizuki. Therefore $R$ is a localization of $B$. Moreover $B$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.

Comment: What are $a_k$ ? And why does $A$ have dimension $1$ ?

Comment: The $a_k$ are the elements appearing in your post. The domain $A$ has dimension $1$ by Noethers normalization theorem.

Comment: Thanks ... some more questions ... I don't see why $B$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra and why is $R$ a localization of $B$ ?

Comment: Both are non-trivial results in commutative algebra: the integral closure of a finitely generated $k$- algebra without zero divisors within its field of fractions is a finitely generated $k$.algebra. Moreover: any localization of a Dedkind domain at a prime ideal is a discrete valuation ring. Apply the latter to the prime ideal $m\cap B$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of $R$.

Comment: Well but I'm not sure why $A$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra ...?

Comment: It isn't. Sorry that I misguided you: a central point of the chain of arguments is that under the given assumptions one can work over the field $k(x)$ and over this field $A$ is by definition finitely generated.